# how to find where & why is server taking too much time to executing the controller function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

i am new to .net environment . I am trying to upload multiple files through UI controller to some other api. it like from UI Js ajax request to  asp.net UI Controller to some other api actual function. when i am uploading one it is uploading . but when is upload multiple files it taking too much time. most of files size are 3 MB.

i am really confuse where or how to know where in IIS taking too much time. because when make direct call to api from js it uploading files very fast but when it went through UI controller it is taking too much time.

i am adding UI Controller code. i

```
    public async Task<JsonResult> DataList()
    {
        var client = GetHttpClientWithBearerToken();
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
        var url = "some url";
        string Rec;
        string File;
        try
        {

            var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            requestContent.Add(new StringContent(HttpContext.Request.Form["Id"]), "Id");


            int FilesCount = HttpContext.Request.Files.Count;            
            for (int i = 0; i < FilesCount; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = HttpContext.Request.Files[i];
                requestContent.Add(new StreamContent(file.InputStream), "file[]", file.FileName);
            }

            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsync(url, requestContent);

            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var returnData = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                var jsonResult = Json(new { success = true, Content = returnData }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

                return jsonResult;
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { success = false, Content = "-1" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logging.WriteLog(e.Message, Logging.LogMsgType.General);
        }
        return Json(new { success = false, Content = "-1" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }`
```

have added some logs but there is not high time in the log so request is taking so much time to reach there. till the time chrome network tab showing [image]

Comment: Probably not the reason, but you shouldn't be doing `.Result` remove it and await instead: `var returnData = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`

Comment: How many and how big are the files you uploading to the 3rd party? A cursory glance of your code suggests the issue is going to be a network I/O issue. To help you further troubleshoot, you should look into `EventCounter` for techniques to measure your controller's performance.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/event-counter-perf

Comment: I suspect the ADD method may be slowing things down.  Check the time for each ADD method and see if the ADD is taking same time of keeps on getting larger.  The Add is creating MIME attachments to the body.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true

Comment: The speed of going to bed has almost nothing to do with iis. Is your iis server configuration information? Are there any special settings, such as load balancing?